# Redis Cluster transactions support

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Is there any support for transactions in Redis Cluster [python client](https://github.com/redis/redis-py)? Obviously the keys participating in the transaction are mapped to the same slot using Hash Tags

For example: how to perform following commands atomically?

```
redis.delete("key1.{123}")
redis.set("key2.{123}", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pipelines](https://github.com/redis/redis-py#pipelines) with transaction=True (default)

```
pipe = redis.pipeline(transaction=True)
pipe.delete("key1.{123}")
pipe.set("key2.{123}", 1)
pipe.execute()
```

Comment: Transaction=True is not supported at the RedisCluster client